# Handle ActiveTabChanged in Ajax TabContainer

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have TabContainer and i generate TabPanel in Page_load method. Each Tab contains button that is created in page_load. How can i handle clicked button in Ajax TabContainer, Knowing that each button has CommandName and CommandArgument.

Comment: Can i ask why you _generate_ `TabPanels` dynamically instead of adding them declaratively (and maybe switch visibility if needed)? What problem do you have with the button's click-event handler?

Comment: Really i bound it with database.

Comment: i mean that each tab represents category and each category has products(buttons) inside the tab.